# How to style SELECT box with using HTML+CSS?

Tags: html, css, select, input

I've got from a designer a form that has **SELECT** inputs made like this:
[image]

I am adding paddings, setting up background, but none of that helping me to prepare the select box the same way as is on the image.

Could I ask you for help guys?

Thank you

Comment: there are a lot of articles, just do a search effort :
http://blog.jambura.com/2013/11/05/style-a-select-box-using-css/
http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Comment: I would have thought some wone with a rep of over 4000 would have provided some code that they had tried so far!

Answer (score 0):

It's Because you can not style select inputs the way you want it.
You'll have to create a custom select.
have a look at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/